# Entity Framework Migrations running in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-deployment

I am moving an application to Azure and I am not sure where I can run my entity framework migrations. We are deploying from github, but I can't run the migrations from the runner due to security policies outside of my control. I need the migrations to run in Azure.

I already have a command line program that runs the migrations, but I am not opposed to running them with the dotnet command (`dotnet ef database update`).

This is something I only need to run once on each deployment.

I got it to work with a container instance, but that doesn't support using KeyVault references for environment variables.  My deployment can't have any secrets and I need to use a KeyVault reference for the connection string.

I thought about a timer-triggered function, but the deployment needs to know that it completed successfully.

What is a good cloud native solution for something that only needs on deployment?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @ Albert Starreveld for the doc.

*There are different approaches on EF migrations running in Azure*

*`Code first` is one approach*

For this approach a Data Model need to be created

[image]

*For the below address class a table is created in database and for the person as well with a unique identifier *

[image]

*Need to use the below NuGet packages to the project*

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```

[image]

*To communicate with the dtabase and model classes
we use the DbContext class,  which is a base class provided by EntityFrameworkCore*

[image]

*To run the below command
you need to install the dotnet-ef tool, and run the below command based on your .net framework version*

```
.NET Core 3: dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.1
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

*And database updates can be done by using teh below command*

```
dotnet ef database update
```

*Updating the database in an Azure DevOps pipeline
for Azure DevOps, there is deployment task for SQL databases. And this task is compatible with the EntityFrameworkCore migrations.
By executing the ‘ef migrations script’ command, a SQL file will be generated that can be used by the SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1 task in Azure pipelines.*

for more information, please check the [link1](https://clearmeasure.com/run-ef-core-migrations-in-azure-devops/) and [link2](https://dotnetthoughts.net/run-ef-core-migrations-in-azure-devops/)

Comment: I don't disagree with this, but it's not relevant to the question.  It's just gerneic information about EF.  In the post, I mentioned why I couldn't use the pipeline.

Comment: Entity framework 6.exe which allows you to make migrations via the command line. In the pipeline you need to move that ef6.exe to where my project assembly file is and execute the migration. This works but for anyone using EF Core, [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/migrate-exe)

Comment: Where will this command line run?  As I meneiton in the post, I can't run it from the pipeline runner.  I need to deploy 'something' to azure and run it there.  What should that 'something' be?  That is the question I am asking.

Comment: Please check this [EF Core Migrations using CLI](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/cli-commands-for-ef-core-migration.aspx)

Comment: I really wish people would read the question before commenting.   The above comment had nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @DonChambers I have a similar-ish problem.  I want my solution to be that I (1) deploy a docker image to an Azure App Service (2) use an ARM `deployScript` to hit a "MigrateDB" endpoint on that App Service and (3) the App Service then runs `SqlCmd` CLI utility to run the EF script.  The one problem: nowhere does anyone know how to install the SqlCmd utility for an image based on `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2022`.  See this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76369548/how-to-add-sqlcmd-to-a-docker-base-image