# How to add `sqlcmd` to a docker base image

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-build

The base image of my Windows dockerfile is:

> mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2022

I need for that image to have `sqlcmd.exe` added to it. So I inserted the following CMD operation:

```
RUN curl -L -o MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2142257 & \
    takeown /F MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi & \
    msiexec.exe /i MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi /quiet /qn /norestart
```

This failed with the following output:

```
Step 5/24 : RUN curl -L -o MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2142257 &     takeown /F MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi &     msiexec.exe /i MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi /quiet /qn /norestart
 ---> Running in c92bc5d7ef44
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 1828k  100 1828k    0     0  1384k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 16.8M

SUCCESS: The file (or folder): "C:\app\MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi" now owned by user "User Manager\ContainerAdministrator".
The command '...<abridged>.... msiexec.exe /i MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi /quiet /qn /norestart' 
returned a non-zero code: 1603
```

That same installer, run from my desktop, works just fine.  So why is `msiexec` choking on `MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi` during my docker build?  What can be done to fix this?  Ultimately, I just want `sqlcmd.exe` installed or otherwise available; if there is better/different way to do this that is fine.

Incidentally, I am not using PowerShell because the aforementioned base image does not have it installed.

Comment: **That URL doesn't download the installer.** It returns (only) a 302 redirect with no body, hence the "Received" bytes = 0. Either get and use the _actual_ URL (which is long and likely unstable) or add `-L` to the curl options so it follows the redirect.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you!  Now I have a new problem.  The `msiexec` command returns a non-zero "1603".  When I isolate the download of the msi, and then interactively run the container...so that I can manually run `msiexec` against the msi...then I get absolutely no result at all.  No error. No message.  In the end, I just want to have sqlcmd.exe available.  Why is this SO HARD??